# Get data asynchronously with Coroutine from Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

so i'm building an export function to export data from Room Database to external file (*.txt file), i'm trying to achieve this by using suspend function from Dao to ViewModel to get all the data, I think i don't really need LiveData because i dont observe it and just calling it one time. Here are the codes

ItemDao

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {

   @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
   suspend fun readItemWithUnits_(): List<ItemModel>

}
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor (private val itemDao: ItemDao): ViewModel() {

   fun readItemWithUnits_(): Deferred<List<ItemModel>> {
       return viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
           itemDao.readItemWithUnits_()
       }
   }

}
```

And calling the Deferred from a Fragment inside withContext(Dispatchers.Main)

Fragment

```
val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()

// Codes before //

 private val writeExample = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        val userChosenUri = it.data?.data
        val outStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openOutputStream(userChosenUri!!)
            lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val listOfItemWithUnit = viewModel.readItemWithUnits_().await()
                var exportContent = "#item_table\n"
                listOfItemWithUnit.forEach { itemModel ->
                    exportContent += "${itemModel.itemId};${itemModel.itemName};${itemModel.itemNote}\n"
                }
                exportContent.byteInputStream().use { input ->
                    outStream.use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Codes After //
```

For now these codes work just fine, the question is, am i doing it correctly? since i will be dealing with a lot of data or is there a better way?

**Edit**

I've tried something like this, change from lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated to CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch

```
 private val writeExample = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val userChosenUri = it.data?.data
        val outStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openOutputStream(userChosenUri!!)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
             val listOfItemWithUnit = viewModel.readItemWithUnits_().await()
             var exportContent = "#item_table\n"
             listOfItemWithUnit.forEach { itemModel ->
                 exportContent += "${itemModel.item.itemId};${itemModel.item.itemName};${itemModel.item.itemNote}\n"
             }
             exportContent.byteInputStream().use { input ->
                 outStream.use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output!!)
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

It return an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
```

And this, without withContext(Dispatchers.Main)

```
 private val writeExample = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val userChosenUri = it.data?.data
        val outStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openOutputStream(userChosenUri!!)
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
             val listOfItemWithUnit = viewModel.readItemWithUnits_().await()
             var exportContent = "#item_table\n"
             listOfItemWithUnit.forEach { itemModel ->
                 exportContent += "${itemModel.item.itemId};${itemModel.item.itemName};${itemModel.item.itemNote}\n"
             }
             exportContent.byteInputStream().use { input ->
                 outStream.use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output!!)
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

It return an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: Why don’t you just directly expose a suspend function instead or returning a Deferred?  It’s not wrong to do that, but it’s kind of awkward. You can remove `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` since the default dispatcher of a lifecycle scope is already Dispatchers.Main. But you do need `withContext(Dispathcers.IO)` wrapped around your blocking file manipulation code.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your code like this

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{ // do your background tasks here 

withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ //do tasks on the main thread that you want with that data

} }
```

Since it is a database operation without anything on the main thread the whole code will be in the CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch block.

Comment: I've tried your code, but it return an error for me. The error says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread". For more context i use Hilt on my app, so the ViewModel and Fragment connected through Hilt Library, i don't know if that is related with this error tho